# In SSIS,How to read the data from Object and mail in the form of Table

Tags: ssis

My main objective is:

1. To read the object which I get through Execute Sql task
2. Then  Using Script task I want to mail it ,but I need to format the values in object in form of table as the body of mail.
3. And IF Time TimeDifference Column had value =<100 Then Row should be Green Else Red.

[image]

So I have an Object called "ResultSet",I pass  to Script Task, I convert it into c# table structure and place it in a variable called "ApplicationTotal".
Below is the code for that which works fine.

```
public void Main()
    {
        DataTable dtTotal = new DataTable();
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        adapter.Fill(dt, Dts.Variables["InactiveSet"].Value);

        // In the first Run dtTotal is created
        if (Convert.ToInt32(Dts.Variables["InsertedRowCountTotal"].Value) == 0)
        {
            foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
            {
               dtTotal.Columns.Add(dc.ColumnName,dc.DataType);
            }
        }
        else // In the next runs dtTotal is retrieved from variable
        {
            dtTotal = (DataTable)Dts.Variables["InactiveSetTotal"].Value;
        }

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            DataRow newDR = dtTotal.NewRow();

            foreach( DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
            {
                newDR[dc.ColumnName] = dr[dc.ColumnName];
            }

            dtTotal.Rows.Add(newDR);
        }

        Dts.Variables["InactiveSetTotal"].Value = dtTotal;
        Dts.Variables["InsertedRowCountTotal"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(Dts.Variables["InsertedRowCountTotal"].Value)  + Convert.ToInt32(Dts.Variables["InsertedRowCount"].Value);

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
```

Then I pass ApplicationTotal object to script task where i have to read the object and mail the details in form of table.I am successful in sending mail but I am not able to format the data in table and change the colour

I get the output in mail as 
[image]

```
        if (Convert.ToInt32(Dts.Variables["InsertedRowCount"].Value) == 0)
        {
            return;
        }


        #region BuildingEmailBody

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendLine(string.Format("Monitor Application Report"));
        sb.AppendLine();
        sb.AppendLine();
        //sb.AppendLine(string.Format("Following are the Details:\n\n<TABLE><TR>\n<TH>{0}</TH><TH>{1}</TH><TH>{2}</TH> <TH>{3}</TH> <TH>{4}</TH>\n</TR>\n", "TimeDifferences(Minutes) ", "UpdateTime", "ApplicationName", "ServerName", "DatabaseName"));

        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();

        if (Convert.ToInt32(Dts.Variables["InsertedRowCount"].Value) > 0)
        {
            sb.AppendLine();
            DataTable ApplicationTotal = new DataTable();
            ApplicationTotal = (DataTable)Dts.Variables["ApplicationTotal"].Value;

            foreach (DataRow dr in ApplicationTotal.Rows)
            {
                sb.AppendLine(string.Format("{0}     {1}      {2}      {3}        {4}  ", dr[0], dr[1], dr[2], dr[3], dr[4]));
            }




            sb.AppendLine();
        }


        # endregion
```

Comment: Sorry, can you add your Script Task code?

Answer (score 0):

In the above code  ,

1.I have taken a variable html in which I create table and load the data in the      table.

2.I add the color coding to the table's rows based on condition

3.Make IsBodyHtml =true

4.Pass html variable to smpt.Send(message)

```
 public void Main()
    {
        string html = string.Empty;
       if (Convert.ToInt32(Dts.Variables["InsertedRowCount"].Value) == 0)
        {
            return;
        }


        #region BuildingEmailBody


        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();

        if (Convert.ToInt32(Dts.Variables["InsertedRowCount"].Value) > 0)
        {
            DataTable ApplicationTotal = new DataTable();
            ApplicationTotal = (DataTable)Dts.Variables["ApplicationTotal"].Value;


            html = "Monitor Application Report <br></br>  <style type='text/css'>td.datacellone {   background-color: #FF0000; color: black;}td.datacelltwo {   background-color:   #00FF00; color: black;}</style> <table border=1>";
            //add header row
            html += "<tr>";
            for (int i = 0; i < ApplicationTotal.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                html += "<th>" + ApplicationTotal.Columns[i].ColumnName + "</th>";
            }
            html += "</tr>";
            //add rows
            for (int i = 0; i < ApplicationTotal.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                html += "<tr>";
                for (int j = 0; j < ApplicationTotal.Columns.Count; j++)
                    if (Convert.ToInt32(ApplicationTotal.Rows[i][0].ToString()) > Convert.ToInt32(Dts.Variables["TimeDifference"].Value.ToString()))
                       html += "<td class='datacellone'>" + ApplicationTotal.Rows[i][j].ToString() + "</td>";
                  else
                        html += "<td class='datacelltwo'>" + ApplicationTotal.Rows[i][j].ToString() + "</td>";


                html += "</tr>";
            }
            html += "</table>";


        }

        //MessageBox.Show(Dts.Variables["TimeDifference"].Value.ToString());
        # endregion

        #region SendingEmail

        string sendTo = Dts.Variables["AlarmOperator"].Value.ToString();
        string from = "pemsadmin@pemsportal.com.au";
        string subject = "Monitor Application Status";

        string server = "192.168.240.171";
        string user = "pemsadmin@pemsportal.com.au";
        string password = "Sawu7619";
        string domain = "pemsportal.com.au";
        int port = 25;

        System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(from, sendTo, subject, html.ToString());

        message.IsBodyHtml = true;
        message.Body = html.ToString();
        System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smpt = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient(server, port);
        smpt.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
        smpt.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(user, password, domain);

        smpt.Send(message);

        #endregion


        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
```